# Shutdown test environment every weekend for cost savings (Azure VMs)

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machines

The powers that be have decided we need to shutdown the entire test domain each weekend, including the DCs and ADFS servers. The admin that decided this is using Azure automation to just stop the instances. This is causing issues with the ADFS database as when it comes back up it's saying unreadable and I have to manually run some powershell commands to get it working again.

Is there a better shutdown method? I've thought about using a running task on the ADFS and DC, to stop the services (powershell stop-service) and the start shutdown before the Azure command comes to stop the instance, but I'm worried that'll still causes issues with ADFS.

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule out the obvious when using the Azure Automation I assume it is waiting to confirm that the servers shutdown in a correct order?  So ADFS Proxy -> ADFS -> DC, then the reverse when powering back up.

Not aware of ADFS having any stability issues when powering up as long as the ADFS can talk to the DC and then the ADFS Proxy to the ADFS.

Comment: Looking at the automation again and nope no order to shutdown, the command to stop is just sent to all servers in the resource group. Then come Monday morning a command is sent to them all to start, so they're all shutting down/starting at essentially the same time. 
I'll investigate getting a more orderly shutdown and startup that should definitely help, completely skipped my mind to check that and would definitely explain things. Thank you!